# Laravel Model::firstOfCreate обработка ошибки

Tags: laravel

Здраствуйте. Только начал изучать Laravel и столкнулся с проблемой. 
В данном случае у меня есть модель User с уникальным полем, которую нужно записать в базу.Первый раз все срабатывает, а после возвращает ошибку SQL, что есть такой дубликат. 
Как мне правильно перехватить ошибку и допустим написать что такой Email уже существует?
Для записи использую User::firstOrCreate.

Пример:

```
   $user = User::firstOrCreate(
                 [
                     'email' => 'mail@mail.mail',
                     'name' => 'Mike',
                     'password' => Hash::make('123')
                 ]);
```

Ответ Laravel

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mail@mail.mail' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `name`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (mail@mail.mail, Mike, $2y$10$yO3Sbjf.UVeOW9I0uSTHQ.xdzxxbBAYjYtYdxNS/zgwOPyKYbEPay, 2020-02-22 09:19:27, 2020-02-22 09:19:27))
```

Comment: По уму делается чуть по другому. Перед записью в базу, нужно сделать проверку, что такой записи нету в БД. И только после этого записывать. Если есть, то вывести ошибку. Удобнее всего делать через валидаторы полей

Answer (score 0):

Извините, если не актуально. В вашем случае вам нужно решить, нужны ли вам уникальные записи или нет. С помощью `User::updateOrCreate` вы можете обновить или создать запись.

Или

Пожалуйста, создайте запрос:

```
php artisan make:request YourRequest
```

**Применить:**

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Rules\Password; // <- это твое правило
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
 
class YourRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Определите, авторизован ли пользователь для выполнения этого запроса.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
 
    /**
     * Получите правила проверки, применимые к запросу.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Вот пример того, как отображать ошибки для определенного поля:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#the-at-error-directive

`php artisan make:rule Password`

И вот правила:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;


class Password implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Создать новый экземпляр правила.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $email
    
    public function __construct(User $email)
    {
        $email = $this->email;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $this->email)->first();
        try {
            if($user === null) {
                throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                    'email' => ['Электронная почта не верна.'],
                ]);
            } else {
                if (! Hash::check($value, $user['password'])) {
                    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                        'password' => ['Неверный пароль.'],
                    ]);
                }
                return true;                
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'password' => [$e->getMessage()],
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получите сообщение об ошибке проверки.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Введенный пароль неверный.';
    }
}
```

Не забудьте включить это правило в свой класс запроса:

`app\Http\Requests\YourRequest.php`

```php
...
    public static function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
            'password' => ['required', new Password()]
        ];
    }
...
```

//////////////////////////

```php
    public function Signup(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first(); // правда или лож
        $error = 'Этот пользователь уже зарегистрирован';
        if(!$user) {
            // create user
        }
        return back()->withErrors(['user' => $error ]); // else
    }
```

///////////////////////////

```php
$user = User::firstOrCreate(
    ['email' => $email], // твоя ошибка здесь
    [
        'email' => 'mail@mail.mail',
        'name' => 'Mike',
        'password' => Hash::make('123')
    ]
);
```

Показан этот ответ, потому что свойство находит первую запись или создает, если нет. Но вы не указали, по какому параметру искать совпадения. В моем примере это электронная почта.

Рад был помочь )

P.S. Sorry for the rough translation

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Comment: Ок. Это есть. Готово.

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку Вы "только начали изучать Ларавел", позволю себе порекомендовать хорошую практику для решения этой, стандартной задачи: Нужно использовать валидацию форм ларавел, тут пример (https://github.com/woskresk/LA-simple-validation-form-request)

1) Создаём класс посредник: php artisan make:request StoreBlogPost и радектируем по примеру:

```
class StoreBlogPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; //!!!ДЛЯ РАБОТЫ ВАЛИДАЦИИ УСТАНОВИТЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ "true"
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'exists:states,abbreviation', // это правило проверки email на существование в базе данных
        ];
    }

    public function messages()  // МЕТОД ДОБАВЛЯЕТСЯ ВРУЧНУЮ. ДЛЯ СОБСТВЕННЫХ ОПОВЕЩЕНИЙ ОБ ОШИБКАХ
    {
        return [
            'email.exists' => 'Пользователь с данным email уже зарегистрирован', // добавляем текст ошибки 

        ];
    }
}
```

2) Меняем в исполняющем методе контроллера

```
public function store(Request $ request)
```

на

```
public function store(StoreBlogPost $ request)
```

3) Оформляем view для вывода ошибок

```
<input  type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email">
                    @error('email')
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    @enderror
```

Все файлы из примера расположены (https://github.com/woskresk/LA-simple-validation-form-request). Если смог помочь поставьте лайк или подписку в github!)